# Probability of a population increasing from size $N$ to size $N + 1$ in a time interval $(t, t + dt)$?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

Let $\lambda$ be the birth rate and consider a time interval $(t, t + dt)$.

If we have a population of size $N$ the probability of it increasing to size $N + 1$ within the interval $(t, t + dt)$  is $\lambda * N * dt$.

But something seems wrong here as we have a probability that may be greater than $1$ which is not possible?

E.g. If $\lambda = 0.5, dt = 0.5$, then if $N$ is, say, $10$, we have that the probability of the population increasing to $11$ is $2.5$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are making $dt$ too big. You are interested in the limit as $dt \to 0$ from above.

Comment: The probability isn't greater than one. The expected number of kids born is greater than one, and that's what you calculated.

Comment: @Arthur It says on page 8 here that it is the probability of the population increasing from $N$ to $N + 1$, not that the expected value that the number born is greater than $1$ - http://www.capital.edu/uploadedFiles/Capital/Academics/Schools_and_Departments/Natural_Sciences,_Nursing_and_Health/Computational_Studies/Educational_Materials/Mathematics/Models%20for%20Birth%20and%20Death%20Processes%20of%20Organisms.pdf

Comment: As Henry said, that's because you're making $dt$ too big. The quantity $dt$ is usually interpreted as an infinitesimal size, which is to say, "in-between" $0$ and any positive real number. In that case, the probability that _more_ than one kid is born is completely negatable. If the time step is supposed to be positive, it's usually written $\Delta t$ instead, and in that case, the probability that two or more kids are born comes into play.

Comment: @Arthur "The expected number of kids born is greater than one, and that's what you calculated." I fail to see where the OP computed the expected number of kids born. "In that case, the probability that more than one kid is born is completely neg(ligi)ble." This seems off-topic with respect to the question asked, no?

Comment: @Did $\lambda\cdot N\cdot \Delta t$ is the expected number of kids born in the time $\Delta t$, if we assume $\Delta t$ to be small enough that those children won't get children of their own. So not exactly right, but the calculation resembles an expected value more than it does a probability if $\Delta t$ isn't really small. Also, if $\Delta t$ gets small enough to make the probability that more than one kid is born negligible (I'm ashamed of that one, by the way), then the expected number of kids born and the probability that a kid is born coincides. That's how it's related to the question.

Comment: @Arthur In other words, you draw attention to a *coincidence*. The relevant fact to answer this question is that $\lambda Ndt$ is, in the suitable regime, an approximation of the probability of interest, not that it is an expectation.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

> If we have a population of size $N$ the probability of it increasing to size $N + 1$ within the interval $(t, t + dt)$  is $\lambda * N * dt$.

This is a loose formulation of the statement that, for every $n\geqslant0$, $$\lim_{s\to0+}\frac{P(N_{t+s}=N_t+1\mid N_t=n)}s=\lambda n.$$ So yes, as you remarked, probabilities are always in $[0,1]$, but *derivatives* with respect to $t$ of probabilities depending on $t$ can take any value.